# How to stop `pandas.read_sql_query` is reformatting dates?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I am connecting to a sqlite database which has date columns which are strings. The dates are formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy".

It seems like no matter what I try, when querying the database with `pandas.read_sql_query()` the string is reformatted to "yyyy-mm-dd".

e.g.

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, db, index_col="Submission", params={"submission": "foo"}, dtype={"Loc_StartDate": str})
```

returns:

```
               Loc_Num          Loc                        County      Loc_StartDate 
Submission                                                                                                
foo              4             foo                 Pembrokeshire         2017-11-23            
foo              0             bar                 Pembrokeshire         2010-03-08           
foo              3             baz                 Worcestershire        2010-11-04         
foo              1             foobar              Carmarthenshire       2010-04-07
```

I have also tried

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, db, index_col="Submission", params={"submission": "foo"}, parse_dates={"Loc_StartDate": {"format": "%d%m%Y"}})
```

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, db, index_col="Submission", params={"submission": "foo"}, dtype={"Loc_StartDate": str}, parse_dates={"Loc_StartDate": {"format": "%d%m%Y"}})
```

and

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, db, index_col="Submission", params={"submission": "foo"}, parse_dates={"Loc_StartDate": {"infer_datetime_format": True}})
```

And all are giving me the same thing with dates formatted as "yyyy-mm-dd".

Comment: Isn't this just the displayed format of the parsed dates? Do you want to parse the date or not?

Comment: How are you displaying the dataframe? It's almost certain that pandas is seeing the date as a date and is storing it as a date in memory, but it's formatting it that particular way when you `print` or `display` or `to_csv()` or what-have-you because that format is ISO standard and default for displaying to us humans. If you can share how you are viewing this dataframe, we can likely help you with formatting the date for that display/view.

Comment: Ok, thanks so this is both when printing the dataframe, but also just running in an interactive python session what's being printed to the screen. The issue I'm facing in reality is that storing the date values in a dictionary, e.g. `{"on_date": row["Loc_StartDate"]}` and then "jsonifying" seems to keep the dates in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, whilst I don't want them to be reformatted from "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: @JNevill, I'm not sure why pandas is seeing the date as a date even when I set "dtype={"Loc_StartDate": str}" ...

Comment: @BigBen, am I being stupid? As far as I'm aware, in my first example, I'm not parsing the date, I am simply querying the database and trying to enforce that the date is kept as a string. It seems as though whatever I do, even if I don't parse the date, the format in which the string is loaded into memory is restructured. Perhaps you could provide an example line of code ...

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my answer. I was opening the CSVs in excel which reformats the iso date string to dd/mm/yyyy, so basically it wasn't pandas doing anything wrong. The last time I'll make that mistake.